Did Jacob prostrate himself before Joseph?
The Gemara in Berachot 55 learns from Joseph's dream that there is no dream without meaningless components; as he had dreamed of the sun, the moon and eleven stars bowing before him, yet Rachel (symbolized by the moon) was already dead.
Is there any indication that Jacob actually prostrated himself before Joseph? If not, would not the sun bowing part also be a meaningless component?

Does Gen 47:31 count וַיֹּ֗אמֶר הִשָּֽׁבְעָה֙ לִ֔י וַיִּשָּׁבַ֖ע ל֑וֹ וַיִּשְׁתַּ֥חוּ יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל עַל־רֹ֥אשׁ הַמִּטָּֽה:

Rashi brings that the moon bowing is the meaningless component - tho Rachel did already bow to Joseph when confronting esav and also her nurse maid might count etc...
